# Manage full content, teaser and trimmed content in template

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

Despite a long time dealing with Drupal I feel quite new to Drupal7 templating. I'm writing a node--product.tpl.php where I need both a full version of **node body** and the **teaser** to be shown. In case no teaser is specifically defined by the website owner I want a **trimmed version of the body** to appear instead of that teaser.

The code for each goes like that:

**Full body**

```
print render($content['body']);
```

**Trimmed body**

```
print "substr(render($content['body']), 0, 100);
```

**Teaser**

```
$body = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
$teaser = field_view_value('node', $node, 'body', $body[0],'teaser');
print render($teaser]);
```

Everything ok until here.

Now the problem is to guess whether there's any teaser. First time a node is created without a teaser, $teaser="" so I check it with

```
if (strlen(render($teaser])) > 1) { //there's a teaser -> print teaser }
```

But if there's a teaser and it has been deleted then it shows as if the teaser is the same as the full body. :-(

So, in short: **What's the proper way to check whether there's a teaser created?**

Thanx in advance,
hip

*BTW: I swear I've checked forums within and out Stackoveflow.com and all I founded has been modules, complicated problems,...*

Comment: Consider putting your solution into an answer and removing it from the question text

Answer (score 0):

OK.

Thanx to [cfox612](https://www.drupal.org/user/770796) and a little search I got it to work. I post my solution here for anyone to make use of it in case you may need it.

```
//retrieve from DB value of teaser                      
$teaser_db_content = db_query("SELECT body_summary FROM {field_data_body} WHERE entity_id=$node->nid")->fetchField();

//check whether there's a teaser defined (under 3 characters is not considered a valid teaser)                      
if (strlen($teaser_db_content)>3){ //it is defined
     $body = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
     $teaser = field_view_value('node', $node, 'body', $body[0],'teaser');
     $post_teaser = render($teaser);
     print $post_teaser; //echo the teaser in HTML
} else { //teaser is not defined
     $post_body = $node->body['und'][0]['value'];
      // check whether there's a body defined
      if (strlen($post_body)>3) { //body defined...
           print substr($post_body, 0, 50)."&nbsp;[...]"; // echo a trimmed version of body
      } else { //no body defined
           print ("No body content defined yet. Wanna help?"); 
      }                         
}
```

Obvious: if you see any inconsistency or way to make it better, simply add a comment. Doubts? Same procedure.